# Can you override an aliased method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alias

In Ruby, when a method is aliased, the alias points to the body of the original method.  So even if you redefine the original method, the alias will continue to use the original definition.

```
class Foo
  def bar
    "bar"
  end  
  alias :saloon :bar
end

class Foo
  def bar
    "BAR"
  end
end

puts Foo.new.saloon
```

will return 'bar' and not 'BAR'.  Is there any way to get saloon to use the new definition of bar?

EDIT: I should have been more clear.  The example was just an illustration of the issue - it's not the actual problem I need to solve.  The issue is more complex when you have chained aliases, for example, in rails' core.  E.g. perform_action is aliased by benchmarking module, and then also by flash module.  So now a call to perform_action is actually calling perform_action_with_flash which does it's thing, then effectively calls perform_action_with_benchmarking which then calls the original perform_action.  If I want to override perform_action_with_benchmarking (even though I agree it's a bad idea - please let's not get into a discussion of that as it's besides the point), I can't because it has been aliased, and as far as I can tell the alias is pointing to what is essentially a copy of the original perform_action_with_benchmarking, so even if I redefine it, there's no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another answer, but you have to do some additional steps: collect the aliases before overriding, and realias after:

```
class Class
  def get_aliases method_name
    original_proc = instance_method method_name
    aliases = []
    instance_methods.each do |meth|
      # if the methods have different names but they're the same, they're aliased
      if meth != method_name.to_s && original_proc == instance_method(meth)
        aliases << meth
      end
    end
    aliases
  end
end

class Foo
  def bar
    "bar"
  end  
  alias :saloon :bar
end

class Foo
  aliases = get_aliases :bar
  def bar
    "BAR"
  end
  aliases.each { |a| alias_method a, :bar }
end

puts Foo.new.saloon  #=> BAR
```

BTW, if anyone can strip off one of that steps, may I know it! :)

Comment: That's a clever way of determining what methods are aliased.  I think it would do the trick...

Answer (score 9):

Just re-establish the alias:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    "bar"
  end  
  alias :saloon :bar
end

class Foo
  def bar
    "BAR"
  end
  alias :saloon :bar
end

puts Foo.new.saloon # => "BAR"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class Foo
  def bar
    "bar"
  end
  def saloon
    bar
  end
end
```

This is not an alias at all, but it works as you want.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.  Either coreyward or Sony Santos's solutions work fine.  What you need to know is why your coded didn't work the way you though.

`alias` makes a new name for the function as is appears when the method is invoked. This is *not* a pointer, but a new way of referring to something.  It allows us to do something like this:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    "bar"
  end  
  alias :speakeasy :bar
end

class Foo
  def bar(secret_code = false)
    return speakeasy if secret_code == "A friend of Al"
    "Closed because of prohibition!"
  end
end

puts Foo.new.bar #=> "Closed because of prohibition!"
puts Foo.new.bar "A friend of Al" #=> "bar"
```

The old bar still exists, it just a little harder to access now.